# I keep getting clang: error: no input files in C++

Tags: c++, file, terminal, ifstream

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    std::ifstream ifs ("strength_classes.txt", std::ifstream::in);

    char c = ifs.get();

    while (ifs.good()) {
        std::cout << c;
        c = ifs.get();
    }

    ifs.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I then compile it in the tutorial by running the following, but it outputs the error:

```
Laptop:Downloads Stu$ c++ -c test.cpp
Laptop:Downloads Stu$ g++ -o test.o
clang: error: no input files
```

Comment: no need to use `using namespace std;`
if you are going to use `std::`

Comment: I think program is unable to find the "strength_classes.txt" fileso instead of providing "strength_classes.txt" provide the complete and clear path inorder to be found by compiler

Comment: Still getting the error :(

Comment: @LiddleLaLoo It wouldn't solve the problem. It was just a comment unrelated to you problem about your coding style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are trying to do the following:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -c -o test.o
$ g++ test.o -o program
```

To run your program type

```
$ ./program
```

afterwards.

Comment: @LiddleLaLoo doesnt that mean success?

Comment: Why doesn't it put anything?

Comment: @LiddleLaLoo You should have an executable named `program` afterwards. You'll have to **run it separately** to see your program working.

Comment: @LiddleLaLoo It is normal behavior. It created the file named `program` ... you can run it now: `./program`

Answer (score 1):

```
g++ -o test.o
```

This is wrong. The `-o` flag is supposed to indicate the filename of the resulting executable, which you're accidentally stating as `test.o` and then failing to provide inputs.

Write:

```
g++ -o myBinary test.o
```

then execute:

```
./myBinary
```